# How do I listen for all trackpad and magic mouse movements?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

This is for Swift, I don't see any way to do this I've been looking all around stack and google.

**Example A:** I'm moving my finger around on the magic mouse but not moving the cursor, how can my app receive these movements?

**Example B:** I'm moving my finger around on a trackpad (causes cursor to move anyways) how can my app receive these movements?

I am not looking to listen for pre-defined gestures, but instead want to let users make their own gestures.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. These are two different things. Mouse position and scroll

Comment: @LeoDabus it's pretty clear, the magic mouse and trackpad are sensitive to touch...i'm asking how to receive that input not the mouse movement or scroll.

Comment: I don't know any input other than position and scroll that you can monitor from a mouse

Comment: @LeoDabus well then how does OSX listen for multi-finger gestures on the mouse and trackpad?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html